# Is there a name for this given type of matrix?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, notation, permutations, latin-square

Given a finite set of symbols, say $\Omega=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, is there a name for an $n\times m$ matrix $A$ such that every column of $A$ contains each elements of $\Omega$?

(The motivation for this question comes from looking at $p\times p$ matrices such that every column contains the elements $1,\ldots, p$).

Comment: Although the columns are permutations of $\{1, \dots, p\}$, do not call it a *permutation matrix* as that already has an established meaning.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thanks for the response. Just to clarify though, I was not thinking of giving a name to such matrices. Rather, I was trying to ascertain if such matrices had already been named and what research had been undertaken on them already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sensible definition for this matrix would be a *column-Latin rectangle*, since the transpose is known as a *row-Latin rectangle*.  Example:

> A. Drisko, [Transversals in Row-Latin Rectangles](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jcta.1998.2894), JCTA 81 (1998), 181-195.

The $m=n$ case is referred to as a *column-Latin square* in the literature (this is in widespread use).

I found one example of the use of column-Latin rectangle here ([ref.](http://www.mathe.tu-freiberg.de/~dempe/Holzhau/Abstracts/dhamala.ps); .ps file).